# Average latitude/longitude calculation?

Tags: latitude-longitude

i want to calculate the Average latitude/longitude,
i want to use the method in this web site (the method C) :http://www.geomidpoint.com/calculation.html

Please i'm not undestand this point can anyone explain this to me :

2. All longitudes in 'Your Places' are adjusted so as to be relative to
   the geographic midpoint longitude calculated in Method A. This helps
   eliminate the problems associated with locations on both sides of
   the International Date Line. For example: lon1 = lon1 -
   lonGeographicMidpoint then if the resulting lon1 lies outside the
   range -180 to 180, then add or subtract 360 to bring it back into
   that range.